# Pass value from Objective-C class to Swift TableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I have a project written mostly in Objective-C. My goal is to migrate step by step all codebase to Swift.

**Base Cell**

```
@interface WACategoryTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) WACategory * category;

@end
```

Here I assign some value to the instance of **WACategory** class in **WACategoryTableViewCell**

```
- (void)configureCell:(WACategoryTableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    WACategory *category = [self categoryAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setCategory:category];
}
```

WACategoryTableViewCell is a base cell.
I have another cell which I implemented programmatically in Swift.
technically Inside of that cell I can use an instance of WACategory class which I created in the base cell.

```
@objcMembers class WACategoryPhotoCell: WACategoryTableViewCell {

    var passedCategory: WACategory? {
        didSet {

        }
    }

    func setupCategory() {
        let url = URL(string: self.category.iconUrl)
        self.iconImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
    }

}
```

However when I try to retrieve category value it has nil.

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong. Maybe there is a proper way to pass value from one Objective-C class to the Swift class.

Comment: Basically there is no special requirements in passing Objective-C objects to Swift objects. In your case I don't see where do you try to retrieve passed category and why should it be already there: in your swift cell class it's not clear why you need `didSet` property observer on `passedCategory` property and where do you call `setupCategory` from

Comment: I assume that you mean category value is nil inside `setupCategory()`? Can you also post the block of code where you set category and call that function?

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific way to pass values from Objective-C to Swift.

But I want to suggest you configure your cell by passing category in `setupCategory` method.

**Updated code:**

```
func setupCategory(with category: WACategory) {
    let url = URL(string: category.iconUrl)
    self.iconImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
}
```